# Javascript / JQuery Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I've got some Node.js going on with some functions in the document ready of jQuery.  I have two files both of which have a document ready.  However, one file calls to the other, and it doesn't recognize the function. ReferenceError: SocketGameOut is not defined

```
=========== File 1 =============

$(document).ready( function () {

var socket = io.connect('http://local.baseball.com:3333');

socket.on('news', function (data) {
    SocketBroadcastIn(data);
});

socket.on('message', function (data) {
    SocketGameIn(data);
});

function SocketGameOut(outstring) {
    socket.emit('clientData', outstring );
}

});

============ File 2 ==============

$(document).ready( function () {

    $("#login").click( function () {

    var loginData = { command: 'login', user: $("#user").val(), pass: $("#password").val() }
    var data = JSON.stringify(loginData);

    SocketGameOut(data);  <--This function call returns 
              ReferenceError: SocketGameOut is not defined

});

});
```

Comment: The easy way out would be to make SocketGameOut global.  For instance, in file1, the last thing inside your `document.ready`, put `window.SocketGameOut = SocketGameOut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions follow the same scope rules as variables (in fact, functions are variables). So if you create a function within another function, it will be visible only in that function.

In the first file you do not need the `$(document).ready` event, because you do not manipulate the DOM. Just remove it and create the variables in the global scope, so they will be visible in other parts of *File 1* and in all files, included after this one.

Another way is to attach this function to a variable outside the `$(document).ready`, so it will be in global scope, but it is unnecessary here and first way will be much better:

```
var SocketGameOut;
$(document).ready( function () {
    //your code...
    SocketGameOut = function (outstring) {
         socket.emit('clientData', outstring );
    }
    //your code...
});
```